# Best practice to validate a form on submit and redirect with Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a simple form:

```
<form id="search-form" >
       <input type="text" name="location" id="search-form-location" value="London">
       <button type="submit">Submit</button>            
  </form>
```

What I want to do is to validate the input field and if everything is ok send the user to a new page that is using the input value as part of the url, not a querystring value, eg "/search/London". If validation fails I would like to handle the information about what field is not correct.

How should I do this?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Try creating a javascript function. Pass the input value to that function and check whether the value is okay and if not you can output messages to user to tell them what the issue is.

Comment: If any of the answer helped you Please mark it as accepted

Comment: @BasheerKharoti there are some good answers, but no one is using on submit event, as asked in the question title. I will wait some time maybe someone will edit

Comment: @MQ87 I've just edited my answer check it back if it  works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<form id="search-form" method="get" >
       <input type="text" name="location" id="search-form-location" value="London">
       <button type="submit" id="search">Submit</button>            
  </form>
```

If you are using `jQuery` then bind submit button click event and handle your requirements:

**Button click event:**

```
$( "#search" ).click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var inputVal = $('#search-form-location').val();
  if(vaildateUserInput(inputVal)) {
    $('#search-form').attr('action', 'search/' + inputVal);
    $("#search-form").submit();
  } else {
     // Show error message to user
  }
});
```

***OR***

**Form Submit event**

```
$( "#search-form" ).submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var inputVal = $('#search-form-location').val();
  if(vaildateUserInput(inputVal)) {
    $(this).attr('action', 'search/' + inputVal);
    $(this).submit();
  } else {
     // Show error message to user
  }
});
```

NOTE: Define `vaildateUserInput()` function which will return `true|false` after validate.

Hope this will helps you. Use the event which best for your requirements.

Comment: why on click instead of $('#search-form').on('submit',..)?

Comment: Both will work! But you have to do `event.preventDefault();` because if data is not validate then you have to restrict form post.

Comment: I think that it's better to use on submit because if someone change the text in the location field and hit return it will be triggered, instead of the handler on click event.

Comment: Updated my answer for form submit as well. Please check.

Comment: Accepted, I like the use of the form "action" instead of window.location.href of other answers

Answer (score 1):

Validate the form,take the form action and append the input value like so

```
<form id="search-form" >
       <input type="text" name="location" id="search-form-location" value="London">
       <button type="button" id="submit_form">Submit</button>            
  </form>
<script>
$("#search-form").on('submit', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    var input_val = $("#search-form-location").val();
    if(input_val != null) { 
       window.location.href = "yourpath/"+input_val;
    } else {
      //do what ever you want
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic example you might have to change stuff around but it works.

**HTML:**

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x == null || x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
}
}
```

See live example here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_validation_js

**This function checks whether the user left the input field empty.**

Answer (score 0):

Use Like

```
<form id="search-form" >
       <input type="text" name="location" id="search-form-location" value="London">
       <button type="button" onclick="validateAndSubmit()">Submit</button>            
  </form>
<script>
function validateAndSubmit(){
var form=document.getElementById('search-form');
if(document.getelementById('search-form-location')!="")
    form.submit();
else 
   alert("location may not be empty")
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="search-form" >
       <input type="text" name="location" id="search-form-location" value="London">
       <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>            
  </form>

$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
  if(  $('#search-form-location').val() != '')
        window.location.replace("url");

});
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Assign an ID to your submit button and input field. You should then use JavaScript to cancel the submit event on button click and validate the captured data however you would like to and display to the user which fields are not valid.

This should be enough to get you started.

Here is an example JavaScript function that you can modify to your liking, don't forget to reference JQuery in your HTML file!

```
$("#your_submit_button_id_here").click(function()
{
    event.preventDefault();
    if($("#some_input_field_id").val().length === 0)
    {
       console.log("The length of the input field is not zero");

       // after all validation is done redirect them to another page
       window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

    }
});
```